# webservices - validating input

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I am playing around with a simple webservice JAX-WS without using any fancy tools ( no usage of CXF or Metro etc )

I am using inbuilt support provided by JDK 1.6.x to create this web service ( JAX-WS RI 2.1.6 in JDK 6 )

My question - I would like to introduce validations in my web service so I thought I would use the "@SchemaValidation"

Tried importing it as well - but code fails to compile

Snapshot of my code:

```
package com.mkyong.ws;
import javax.jws.WebService;
**import com.sun.xml.ws.developer.SchemaValidation;**


@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.mkyong.ws.HelloWorld")
**@SchemaValidation()**  
public class HelloWorldImpl implements HelloWorld{
```

While compiling I get the exception :

```
javac com\mkyong\ws\HelloWorldImpl.java
com\mkyong\ws\HelloWorldImpl.java:3: package com.sun.xml.ws.developer does not exist
import com.sun.xml.ws.developer.SchemaValidation;
                           ^
com\mkyong\ws\HelloWorldImpl.java:8: cannot find symbol
symbol: class SchemaValidation
@SchemaValidation()
^
2 errors
```

So my question is :
Can we not use this annotation with JDK1.6 implementation of RI ?
Do I need to import any special jar's in my classpath ?
Thanks,
satish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to JarFinder:

http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/com.sun.xml.ws.developer.SchemaValidation

- jaxws-rt-2.1.4.jar
- jaxws-rt-2.1.3.jar

*Edit* - I do not know what exactly that annotation is used for but:

1. It is possible to use JAXB (hence JDK 1.6 alone) to validate an XML payload using the `Unmarshaller` class. Have a look to `Unmarshaller.setSchema()`, I also have some examples, let me know if you need them.
2. Judging from the annotation's namespace, it looks more like something internal (`com.sun.xml...`)

Comment: thanks - alessandro - so does this mean that the standard JDK 1.6 does not support schema validations ? Also might sound stupid - but the above two jars you mention - who is the provider of these jars - I will google as well - but just curious of who the providers are - and if it is provided by the Java guys - why was this not a part of JDK 1.6 ? and also then were these JAR's included in some higher version of JDK ?

Comment: Edited the answer to address your question above.

Answer (score 0):

Try to consider to use a wsdl. In the wsdl
You can add all kind of validations.
The validation rules in the wsdl are independant of the language you use to implement your webservice

Answer (score 0):

Use `@SchemaValidation` from the `com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer.SchemaValidation` package on the service implementation bean if you wish to use the annotation shipped with the JDK. I must note though, I've seen at least two instances where people have had issues using the annotation in this package.

The annotation you're attempting to use is bundled with glassfish's JAX-WS RI in the `com.sun.xml.ws.developer.SchemaValidation` package, so you'll need to include it in your project's classpath if you want to make use of that instead